# gmusicbrowser alternative?

Tags: xubuntu, music

I have been tinkering with xubuntu recently and I found the player, gmusicbrowser, to be lacking in some aspects.

I am looking for a lightweight music player that can handle web radio stations, podcasts, use GTK so it blends well with xfce and optionally handle video in podcasts.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Beatbox](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/beatbox-music-player-sees-new-release-on-ubuntu) suits your needs?

Comment: Minimalist, nimble and actually lighter on resources than gmusicbrowser. I love what the elementary team are doing with their apps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) because it is lightweight, usable, built in GTK, allows for music, web radio, RSS feeds (podcasts), is fast, and doesn't need a lot of screen real estate to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

[DeaDBeeF](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/) and [Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org) are quite cool.